# Count line qty and check witch has less qty

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

```
class SaleOrderLine(self)
    inherit = 'sale.order.line'

def check_lowest_qty(self):
    for line in self:

        #print line product_uom_qty with least or biggest negative quantity
```

**Updated question with better grammar.** I want to compare the quantity of each line and to print line which has the least quantity or biggest negative quantity.

**For example.**

If there are 2 lines and first lines quantity is 5 and second lines quantity is -2 I want to print line with -2.

Comment: `check_lowest_qty` method should be in `sale.order` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sorted()` on the recordset and just get the first entry if there is one:

```py
def check_lowest_qty(self):
    self.sorted(key=lambda line: line.product_uom_qty)
    print self[0] if self else None
```

If you want the order reversed use `self.sorted(key=lambda line: line.product_uom_qty, reverse=True)`